# Center Div inside Div with width as auto

Tags: html, css

I have a Div1, and Div2 inside Div1.
Div2 has image and variable length text in it, I want to keep the width of Div2 as auto and center it in the Div1.

As described below:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Div1                                                              |
|               +-------+--------------------+                      |
|               | Image |  Some Test Text    | <- Div2: Width:auto; |
|               +-------+--------------------+                      |
|                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to create it but facing issue to cover the background Div to text and image, actually I want to keep Div height and width as Auto but it is not working as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/2vhr4nLz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you should use css3 [**`flexbox`**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for this.

```
.text-and-image-holder {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

Above css will create the following layout as you can see in working snippet that text and image will be vertically middle aligned with respect to each other:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|            |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit   |
|            |  amet, lorem ipsum dolor |
|            |  sit amet, lorem ipsum   |
|   <img>    |  dolor sit amet, lorem   |
|            |  ipsum dolor sit amet,   |
|            |  lorem ipsum dolor sit   |
|            |  amet, lorem ipsum       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

```css
.image-style {
  margin-right: 20px;
} 

.text-style {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.text-and-image-holder {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-and-image-holder">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" class="image-style">
  <div class="text-style">Vertically Center Text Here</div>
</div>
<div class="text-and-image-holder">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" class="image-style">
  <div class="text-style">Very long text Vertically Center Here and lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Muhammad Usman:  Thanks for the answer, but I need to align entire red box in the middle, and red box should take only width that would fit text and image inside it. and rest of the part should show Div1 which is at background;

Comment: @A_user Is it what you need? [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mfm4jw0z/)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: Aha .. yes that is what I am looking for thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood, you can wrap all your content into a  and then add this to your css

```
.wrapper {width:100%; text-align: center }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Auto width: You can use CSS3 Flexbox.

For fixed width:   

I modified your code and following are the changes;

    HTML:
    <div class="div1">
       <div class="div2">
          <img src="#">
          <span >Vertically Center Text Here</span>
       </div>
    </div>

    CSS:

    .div1 {
      background: red;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .div2 {
      background: white;
      margin: auto;  
      width: 350px;
    }
```